# How to hide/masquerade password in script

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I use the following script to change Open Directory (Apple's LDAP) passwords.

I don't like leaving the actual password within the script -- is there any way to hide or masquerade this so the script can be used by other users, but in a way they can't see the password?

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH
echo
echo Enter username you\'d like to change password for:
read USERNAME 
echo
echo Enter New Password for "$USERNAME"
read PASSWORD
dscl -u diradmin -P 'secretpasswordhere' /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 passwd /Users/$USERNAME $PASSWORD
echo Password successfully changed for $USERNAME to $PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the script run as Set-GID and then get the password information from a file protected under this group.  The group of course should have limited access and membership.  This is a very simple answer.

Another idea is to have the user enter a decrypt code for the scrambled password contained in the scripting.  Thus only authorized users (those with the decrypt code) could run the script.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `shc`

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/

```
 The whole logic behind the shc is to convert the random.sh 
   shell script to random.sh.x.c C program (and of course compile that
   to generate the random.sh.x executable)
```

- random.sh is the original unencrypted shell script
- random.sh.x is the encrypted shell script in binary format
- random.sh.x.c is the C source code of the random.sh file. This C
  source code is compiled to create the above encrypted random.sh.x
  file.

Comment: SHC looks like an elegant solution, but alas it doesn't appear to compile properly in OSX...rats

Comment: Maybe it uses some linux-specific system calls. But in any case you got the idea. It should not be very difficult to create your own version.